# Background-size: contain; Height doesn't scale correctly

Tags: css, webbrowser-control, background-size

I am wanting to keep one image in place while the background image is scalable in browser.

When I use the height: XXXpx; it will not scale correctly. I've also tried using percentages for the height.

```
.cbp-fwslider ul li > a img {
   border: none;
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 100%;
}

.big-o {
   position: absolute;
   top: 360px;
   margin-left: 7%;
   width: 200px;
   height: 358px;
}
```

www.georges.larsonplusyou.com

Thank you guys.

Comment: your missing a semi-colon after the margin-left and missing a closing brace after your first selector, the following styles won't work

Comment: I just missed it when typing it. The live code has the proper syntax.

Comment: Why don't you put an fiddle example...

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the inline style for width from your html, and then change your selector to style the image itself as follows:

```
  .big-o img {
       position: absolute;
       top: 360px;
       margin-left: 7%;
       max-width: 100%
       width: auto;
       height: auto;
    }
```

This worked in my browser, but I would suggest using media-queries for responsive design. I think you need to do a `width: auto\9;` if the webpage will be used in Internet Explorer because there's a bug.

Comment: Hmm. I must be missing something. I removed the inline style and added the img selector..The beer mug is still not moving with the image. If I have the peopleseatgeorges.jpg image at a specific height I would be able to have the beer mug to stay at the same place with the image. If I make the peopleseatgeorges.jpg image at a fixed height the mug stays where it needs to.